# Pre-filtering in a Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I am trying to pre-filter a kendo grid, and I have a problem. 
For pre-sorting and pre-grouping I am using first 2 lines, that work great:

```
grid.DataSource(ds =>
{
    var ajaxDsBuilder = ds.Ajax();
    // ...
    ajaxDsBuilder.Sort(sort => sort.Add(col.Name).Ascending());
    ajaxDsBuilder.Group(grp => grp.Add(col.Name, typeof(string)));

      // problem at the next line with filter
    ajaxDsBuilder.Filter(f=> f.Add(c=>col.Name.ToString()).IsEqualTo("something"));
```

which is giving me a server error after running.

For pre-filtering I found this :

```
.Filter(filter => filter.Add(/* your filter rule */))
```

If I remove the ToString() I get the error: Property with specified name: col.Name cannot be found on type: System.Data.DataRowView

If I try:
  `ajaxDsBuilder.Filter(f=> f.Add(c=> c.col.Name).IsEqualTo("something"));`

I get the **error**:

> An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

I have also tried to use dynamic lambda but the same problems appear ...

What am I missing? 
P.S. I am new to all this, so any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I answered the same question on Telerik forum and I got my answer:

> .Filter(filter => filter.AddRange(new [] {
>        new Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor(col.Name, Kendo.Mvc.FilterOperator.IsEqualTo, "TEST") })

In case someone needs this :)